# How to create dynamic route for top-level page in NEXT?

Tags: next.js

To support these URLs:

- `/account?tab=profile`
- `/account?tab=pass`
- `/account?tab=points`

I know that I can change them to:

- `/account/profile`
- `/account/pass`
- `/account/points`

And then create this route:

`/pages/account/[tab].js`

But this means that the `accoun` is a directory, not a file.

I want to have a `account.js` top-level file, and have a route for query strings on it.

I don't know how to do it. Something like `/account?[tab]` route. Is it possible?

Comment: _"this means that the `accoun` is a directory, not a file"_ - Why is that an issue? You can still have `/account/index.js` that will handle the `/account` path, in addition to the dynamic `/account/[tab].js` route.

Answer (score 0):

```
import type { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from 'querystring';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

const About: NextPage<{ query: ParsedUrlQuery }> = ({ query }) => {
    console.log(query);

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <main className={styles.main}>
                <h1>About</h1>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
    return {
        props: {
            query
        }
    }
}

export default About
```

Comment: dear @Tanishk, as I said in my question, I want to have `account.js` page, not `account` directory.

Comment: In that case, create an account.js file and access tab property using (const { tab } = useRouter().query)inside the file and then use if/else statements to render particular component (profile, pass, points), like this [link](https://github.com/tanishq-singh-2301/tanishq-motors/blob/master/components/invoiceRes.tsx#L54-L75)

Comment: The point is, the `query` object is `{}` when using your suggestion, and in the link you sent I saw that you are not using `router.query` anywhere. You're getting the `operation` variable as a prop.

Comment: @HosseinFallah I edited my last answer try that if that works.